# How to load other library in git repo from jenkins shared library?

Tags: jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm using 2 shared libraries. (A, B)

A is using the B shared library, and I am trying to write a test code, but the B library is not recognized.

Both are in the github enterprise repository.

### Purpose

import library B from workspace A to a git address without downloading it locally
(== groovy import library from git url)

### code

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy
package deploy.util;
import deploy.tcd.DeployUtil

def notifyStarted(String doorayNotifyUrl, Map deployInfo) {
    def n = new dooray.Notify()
```

As a result of building with intelliJ, the following error occurs.

```
6: unable to resolve class dooray.Notify
 @ line 6, column 10.
    def n = new dooray.Notify()
```

A: Currently built library
B: dooray

B library is another shared library registered with jenkins configuration. How do I import it in order to build successfully?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community sorry, added enough code.